# 3G internet access and incoming call simultaneously in android?

Tags: android, 3g-network

Hi I am going to develop application when coming incoming call i want to check the phone number is existing in my application database i want to display the details about the number.
my thought is when 3g coming simultaneously working internet access and voice call?

Comment: :could u be more precise

Comment: On most providers, you should be able to use the internet while the call is only ringing. The data connection is interrupted once the call is answered however.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A incomminc call has always the highest priority. Whenever you got an incomming call, your internet connection stops. You could consider making an app that gets the information after a call and display it the next time the number calls.

Comment: That is incorrect. An *ringing* call will not stop your internet connection on most providers; the data will be available until you *answer* the call.